# Windows Batch file split string %%i was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to set few variables from systeminfo command in Windows. I read all kinds of similar threads and tried various things, but always keep getting the same error:

```
%%G was unexpected at this time.
```

or

```
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

I've been trying to get this done all day long. Can someone point me in the right direction please? This is what I have tried so far:

```
for /f "tokens=:" %%i in ('systeminfo ^| grep "OS Name"') do set OSname=%%i

for /f "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i in ('systeminfo ^| grep "OS Name"') do set OSname=%%i

FOR /F "usebackq delims=  tokens=2" %%i IN ('systeminfo ^| grep "OS Name"') DO set vers=%%i


for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('systeminfo ^|grep "OS Name"') do (set OS_Name=%%a)

systeminfo | find "OS Name" > osname.txt
for /f "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i in (osname.txt) do set osname=%%i


FOR /F %%G IN (FINDSTR /L /C:"OS Name" systeminfo.txt) DO ECHO %%G
```

UPDATE: I got it to work like this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %i IN (`FINDSTR /L /C:"OS Name" systeminfo.txt`) DO set osname=%i
```

Any way to remove the leading space in front of the string? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around the command you are trying to execute in the last FOR command.  Why are you using `GREP`.  The native `FIND` or `FINDSTR` commands should work just fine.

Comment: All of the commands produce the same error about %%i was unexpected. I just need one to work. P.S. the one with GREP was trying to use the GNU for Windows tool. Running from CMD prompt.

Comment: Are you running these commands from a batch file or from the cmd prompt?

Comment: Read the HELP for the `FOR` command.  It clearly says `%variable` is the syntax you are supposed to use and if you are using the `FOR` command in a batch file the help file says use `%%variable`

Comment: Good catch on the %% vs. %. I tried running from .bat file or using a single % in CMD, still no go.

Comment: You first `FOR /F` command will have no problems running in a batch file. Your second and third and fourth `FOR /F` commands do not work because you are using the `USEBACKQ` option but you are not using a back quote.  You are using a single quote.  And I already pointed out what was wrong with your fifth.

Comment: Duh!  `Tokens=:` is not correct.  I assume you meant to use `delims=:` in your first `FOR` command.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2*" %i in ('systeminfo ^| find /I "OS Name"') do set "OSname=%k"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to get the OS name.

```
 for /f "tokens=2* delims=: " %%i in ('systeminfo ^| find "OS Name"') do set OSname=%%j
```